# How to make single digit number a two digit number in ruby?

Tags: ruby, number-formatting

`Time.new.month` returns a single digit representation of any month prior to October (e.g. June is `6`), but I want a 2-digit format (i.e. instead of `6` I want `06`).

I wrote the following solution, and I am asking to see some other/better solutions.

```
s = 6.to_s; s[1]=s[0]; s[0] = '0'; s #=> '06'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For your need I think the best is still

```
Time.strftime("%m")
```

as mentioned but for general use case the method I use is

```
str = format('%02d', 4)
puts str
```

depending on the context I also use this one which does the same thing:

```
str = '%02d %s %04d' % [4, "a string", 56]
puts str
```

Here is the documentation with all the supported formats: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Comment: This works great when using random generators like Forgery. `month = '%02d' % (Forgery(:date).month :numerical=>true);` `day = '%02d' % (Forgery(:date).day)`

Answer (score 28):

You can use this `printf`-like syntax:

```
irb> '%02d' % 6
=> "06"
```

or

```
str = '%02d' % 6
```

So:

```
s = '%02d' % Time.new.month
=> "06"
```

See the documentation for [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 11):

Mat's answer pointing out that you can use the `%` operator is great, but I would like to point out another way of doing it, using the `rjust` method of the `String` class:

```
str = 6.to_s.rjust(2,'0')  # => "06"
```

Comment: Work's perfect for conversion month integer to long month number <%= f.select :card_exp_month, options_for_select((1..12).map {|m| [m.to_s.rjust(2,'0'), m]}) %>

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to format an entire date or date and time (rather than just the month), you might want to use [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392):

```
m = Time.now.strftime('%m')
# => "06"
t = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%z')
# => "2011-06-18T10:56:22Z-0700"
```

That will give you easy access to all the usual date and time formats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sprintf:

```
sprintf("%02d", s)
```

e.g. in irb:

```
>> sprintf("%02d", s)
=> "06"
```

Comment: Are Kernal.sprintf and Kernal.format the same thing? The ruby online document put both in the same place, Is it an alias of each other?

Comment: @yozloy: Yes, [`Kernel.sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001433) and `Kernel.format` are the same thing and pretty much the same thing as the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127).