# Ruby on rails send function bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, send

Its very strange whats happening, Im making a loop to change an html and need to change the variable called product01, the code:

```
(10..34).each do |i|      
      li = @doc.css('li')[i-1]
      li.content = @site.send("product0#{i-9}")
end
```

In the code above, the error says: undefined method `product010' for...

Then I just removed the 0:

```
(10..34).each do |i|      
      li = @doc.css('li')[i-1]
      li.content = @site.send("product#{i-9}")      
end
```

And the error now says: are undefined method `product1' for...

Ive already tried

`@site.send("product"+"0"+"#{i-9}")` > product010

`@site.send("product0".to_s+"#{i-9}")` > product010

`@site.send("product"+"0#{i-9}"` > product010

So, I just want the product01.

To make things more clear, Im using nokogiri to open an html and change values via db, into the db the variables are called product01, product02, etc.

I can say @site.product01 but theres a lot of products so I want to make a loop instead one by one.

Its not an array of products, each product comes from one @site.

Yes, it works when |i| are higher than 10 but not from 0 to 9 because I need to put the 0.

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("/home/file.html")
```

To make it work Ill remove all variables called 01,02..09 and change their names to 1,2,..9 if it wont work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you are trying to do?  eg what is @doc, what is @site, etc?  Why can't you just say `@site.product01` instead of mucking about with send?

Comment: Does it work if you say `@site.send("product#{i}")`?  i will range from 10 to 34 within that loop, giving you `product10`, `product11`....`product34`.   This feels like a horrible solution to a simple problem though.  I'd expect to just have an array of products and iterate over the array instead of accessing loads of different methods.

Comment: why you want to loop for 10..34? why don't you just take length of array or element whatver you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want product01 to product34, that looks wrong.

Is it possible to structure it as a 'products' array? That would be a lot more standard.

However, you can format a number to a given number of digits...

```
irb> '%02d' % 6
=> "06"
```

This would seem to solve the problem.

(taken from [How to make single digit number a two digit number in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397468/how-to-make-single-digit-number-a-two-digit-number-in-ruby))

Comment: Sure, it looks wrong, I'll make 1,2,3.. instead of 01,02,03...
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question. What is the source of the productXX methods/variables? Where is this coming from? - It seems that this code will break down when you have a different site with a different number of products.

Comment: The number of products will be from 1 to 20 always, its one site and people can add from 1 to 20 products. The source of the productXX in schema looks like :site, :productXX, :string and there I have declared from product1 to product20.

Comment: I still having the issue after changing 01 to 1 and using @site.send("produto#{i-8}")

Comment: This is very unusual. A more standard way would be to have a Product model (even if this only had a single string and a site_id in the table) and and put `has_many :products` in your Site model. This means it'll handle a differing number of products much better.

Comment: Hmm, thanks very much, I'll change this so. I am just starting with Ruby on Rails and generated all stuff via scaffold.

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought I'd make sure you knew you'd chosen an unusual route and that this use of send was a more complex work-around than you need. Here's an article which explains the concept https://quickleft.com/blog/introduction-to-database-design-on-rails/ and here's one about implementing it in rails. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks again @AJFaraday I'll read the links you sent and already checked your blog too, great one. Regards.